# Serial Parity/Wakeup Bit Beginning of Packet

Tags: c#

The protocol I am working with uses the Parity (Wakeup) bit to signal the beginning of a new message over RS-232 - all other bytes of the message have the Parity bit set SPACE. Packet contains length and CRC... 
I need to be able to catch the first byte with the Wakeup bit set and then process the packet from the length information in the message itself. 
I have done this in several application in assembly and c.
I am moving to C# and just need help in triggering the start of the capture of the message from the Parity/Wakeup bit of the packet frame - 11 bit with 1 start, 1 stop, 8 data and the Wakeup bit.

Comment: What do you have so far? Are you just having trouble detecting the Wakeup bit? It looks like it's the LSB in the packet... so, assuming you store the packet in a UInt16: if((packet & 1) != 0) // LSB is set

Comment: Knowing you did it in `assembly and c`, in what point have you got stuck while using c#.

Comment: The assembly and c application were on embedded devices that allowed my to see the raw packet bit. C# and other languages it seems allow you to easily see the data section of the packet but handles the frame bits of the packet for you. I will eventually need to send messages that have the first packet frame wakeup bit set and all other packets wakeup set to 0.